# Issue with the GKSession . Cant identify the available devices

Tags: iphone, gamekit, gksession

Hi All I am using the following code to identify the available devices on bluetooth.

```
_session = [[GKSession alloc]initWithSessionID:sessionid displayName:sessionid sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];

_session.delegate = self;

[_session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];

_session.available = YES;
```

I have alos  added the delegate method

```
 - (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state{

NSLog(@"state : %@",state);

switch (state)
{
    case GKPeerStateConnected:
    {

        NSLog(@"%@ connected ",peerID);

        break;
    }
    case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
    {

        NSLog(@"%@ disconnected ",peerID);
        break;
    }
    case GKPeerStateAvailable:
    {
        NSLog(@"Available : %@",peerID);
        break;
    }
    case GKPeerStateUnavailable:
    {
        NSLog(@"Un Available : %@",peerID);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
   }

 }
```

But this method is never being called . What can be the issue ? 
Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1):

well, code seems fine.
do you have delegate declared properly? I mean < GKSessionDelegate > in your .h ?

Could you try initializing GKSession without displayName:

```
_session = [[GKSession alloc]initWithSessionID:sessionid displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they use the same sessionID. Try NULL as session ID instead and the app will make one for you.